# How to show all the categorys in a page in joomla3.0

Tags: html, joomla3.0

How to shows three different categories in a page in joomla3.0. and I want to get each category details when press that category

**please see this Eg**: http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/42980.html

In this web-page take "**Services**" page this page i want exactly please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of extensions and all follow this steps you will get it.
this steps are in joomla3.0 .

STEP 1 :  take **Menu Manager** and take **main menu**.
STEP 2 :  in **main menu** take **choose your own page** (here am selecting  services page.inthe place you can take any pages eg : about,products.....etc).and change the **Menu Item Type** into **Gallery view**(click the **select button** that time open a window in that window click the **Articles** here you can see the list of some Menu Items select **Gallery view** )
STEP 3 :Now take **Advanced option**  in there you can see **Blog Layout Options** here we some arrangements in there you can see  **Intro Articles**(enter the numbers you Articles how much you want to show in a page),**Columns**(Numbers of columns), **Multi Column Order**(change this to **Across**), **Show Filter**(change this to **SHOW** ) 
STEP 4 : press save button and refresh it and see how is your page now.

> Blockquote : need want one or more subcategory in that category which you selected in the* **Choose a category** field .

Answer (score 0):

Check this Extensions
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction/19217

demo : http://demo.tzportfolio.com/

Comment: Through admin we can do this(i mean without extensions)we can do this ha

Answer (score 0):

yep it's http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ what you are looking for and TZ Portfolio linked by chermanarun is using it ;)